# Why does Java AWT Robot not work on a game window?

Tags: java, windows, automation

I am currently experimenting with java awt robot and now I wanted to try to press something inside my game window.

For steam.exe, I put the following properties:
"compatibility to Windows 7",
"always run as administrator".

Then, I launched the game "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive" with this .bat file:

```
@echo off
start "" "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe" -login username password -applaunch 730 -low -nohltv -nosound -novid -window -w 400 -h 300 +exec autoexec.cfg -x 0 -y 0
```

The game launched and now I wanted to click something in the game with the following code:

```
public static void keyStroke(int x, int y) throws AWTException
    {
        Robot robo = new Robot();
        robo.mouseMove(x, y);
        delay(1000);//milliseconds
        robo.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
        delay(100);
        robo.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
    }
```

Here is a picture of the game:
[image: Picture of the game]

The mouse goes to the correct location but when it should be clicking something, the game does not respond or recognize it.

However, if I **do not** put steam.exe in windows 7 compatibility, it works...
Why does robot not work anymore if the game is in windows 7 compatibility mode ?
Unfortunaetely I need to find a fix for this because I can only run steam in win7 comp.
Are there ways to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I needed to run eclipse as administrator. My bad